# Continuous Integration testing a plugin system | Travis CI

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I already have a way to test some of my own plugins' integrations with my main project, but how would I test the integration of the plugin from the plugins' `.travis.yml`?

Could I just put:

```
before_script:
  - cd ../..
  - git clone https://github.com/czipperz/vick czipperz/vick
  - cd czipperz/vick
  - mkdir -p plugins
  - cd plugins
  - git clone my-plugin
  - cd ..
script:
  - make
  - make test
```

What should I do to clean up afterword or should I not worry about it?

Comment: i think you can just not worry about it. you might want to look into their container based infrastructure also, it could streamline your build i think

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 0):

They clean it up automatically, don't worry about it.